# Downloading the App images in iPhone Application settings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, settings.bundle

In my App i download the images and save it in the App. I want that downloading option in iPhone Application settings using Settings.bundle. I dont know if it is possible and would like to get help from others.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can do this in App only there is no option present that can download in setting bundle...

Comment: Why would you want to do that?